# Copy excel formatted data to clipboard from web

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel

I'm looking to provide a button on my page, that when clicked, would copy (excel formatted) data to the users clipboard and they are able to paste in excel with values separated by columms. Is this possible, maybe jquery? I have a understanding and experience with OOP.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Is it a requirement to save it to clipboard? once they click on the button can the page automatically given them the option to download in excel? this option would be much easier.

Comment: Yes that would be easier but unfortunately wouldn't be as effective. We find the tech are copy and pasting a lot of redundant data back and forth and are looking into ways to just grab the content and enter it in. Data would have to be strictly formatted by only selecting certain element values.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be difficult to find a simple solution in JS which is cross browser (It is simple for IE but not for other browser), so you can take a look at ZerClipboard which is a good solution using Javascript and Flash.

[ZeroClipboard](https://github.com/jonrohan/ZeroClipboard)

Comment: Thanks for the info. Greatly appreciated. This is a local network application and all our users use IE. What I had in mind was being able to grab active browser window data by id and have it be copied to the clipboard. I'm also looking into VBA Grab Active Window in excel. Sorry if this may be a little confusing.

Comment: So, maybe you can try `clipboardData.setData("Text", s);` which should copy your text (check first with `if(window.clipboardData && clipboardData.setData)` that will verify if the function exist).

Comment: I think this will get me started. Thank you so so much! Really means a lot. I know enough to get me in trouble, as they say :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function ClipBoard()
{
var tab      = "    ";
var ticket   = $('#Userid').text();
var queue    = $('#queue').text();
var customer = $('#customer').text();
var res      = $('#res').text();

var str      = ticket+tab+queue+tab+customer+tab+res;

$('#holdtext').append(str);
Copied = holdtext.createTextRange();
Copied.execCommand("Copy");
}
```

Using Jquery and inserting tabs in-between each var will format for excel. This only works in IE though.

```
<TEXTAREA ID="holdtext" STYLE="display:none;"></TEXTAREA>
<span id="ticket">767-45</span><br />
<span id="queue">john_doe</span><br />
<span id="customer">Citibank</span><br />
<span id="res">jan_doe</span><br />
<BUTTON onClick="ClipBoard();">Copy to Clipboard</BUTTON>
```